# com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest cant handle big file in post request

Tags: web.xml, multipart

I am getting big files from client. I am using MultipartRequest to handle the request.
but its throwing exception

```
java.io.IOException: Posted content length of 3921442 exceeds limit of 1048576
```

I tried by adding following code(filter) in web.xml. but its not working

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
            <param-value>5000000</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the request constructor:

```
public MultipartRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                      String saveDirectory,
                      int maxPostSize)
```

There you can specify the maxPostSize which is a limit of file size.